# Avoid accidental rebuild of a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, rebuild

I often click on "rebuild" by accident when I actually want to click "build". This rebuild process may take so long time if there are dependencies of this project...

Do you know any plug-in or a configuration that makes visual studio to ask me if I am sure to rebuild this project?

I hope there is a way to handle this situation.

Comment: Have a look at IncrediBuild by www.xoreax.com. While it doesn't prevent you from doing the wrong thing, it definitely helps makeing the outcome of doing so less painful.

Comment: It certainly was a stupid design decision to place these two menu entries next to each other. Makes me ask whether the VS devs ever use their own product.

Comment: @karx11erx: it makes no sense to not put them next to eachother. Maybe the VS devs just have decent eye-hand coordination? :)

Comment: @sbi: it is good that i use IncrediBuild for these large build precesses but anyway i loose time even with IncrediBuild but before IncrediBuild there were so many times that i wanted to kill the VS developers :p

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to **Tools**, **Customize**. Amend the menus and/or toolbars to suit you. For example you might prefer a custom toolbar that contains just the functionality you want without a Rebuild button on it.

Also try bypassing the mouse altogether with the keyboard shortcut for build: **Ctrl+Shift+B**. There is no default keyboard shortcut for rebuild so there's no chance of activating that accidentally. (Also, the keyboard shortcuts can also be changed by clicking **Keyboard** at the bottom of the Customize dialog.)

Comment: +1: I just did this. I had to go to Tools->Customize->Commands, hit the Context Menus radio button, and then hit the combo box and select "Project and Solutions | Project". That brought up the project context menu, where Build and Rebuild were together. I moved down Rebuild, tres bien!

Answer (score 2):

Press F6 to Build (or Shift+F6 to build just one project). There is no hotkey for rebuild in any of the default setups (I think), so you can't hit it by accident ;)

Answer (score -3):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> to cancel a build.

Comment: after cleaning the whole solution, do you think it matters to stop build?